# Groovy, "try-with-resources" construction alternative

Tags: groovy

I'm a new to Groovy. I used to use 'try-with-resources' construction in my Java code during work with I/O streams.

Could you please advise, is there any analogue of such construction in Groovy?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have a look at [the docs on `Groovy IO`](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_io) and the associated javadoc.
It presents the `withStream`, `withWriter`, `withReader` constructions which are means of getting streams with auto-closeability

Comment: URL in this post is no longer available

Comment: Official groovy docs: http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_io

Answer (score 70):

Groovy 2.3 also has [`withCloseable`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#withCloseable(groovy.lang.Closure)) which will work on anything that implements [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)

#### Groovy 3 newsflash

And Groovy 3+ supports try..with..resources as Java does

https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#_arm_try_with_resources

Comment: I remember Luke(alkemist)'s tweet looking for this functionality. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro Yeah, unfortunately, it's going to clash horribly [with my version](https://github.com/timyates/groovy-common-extensions#withclosable), so I'm going to have to do some renaming I reckon...

Comment: I can see a difference with the naming. :) `withClosable` vs `withCloseable`

Comment: @dmahapatro Yay! Less work for me! Hooray for ambiguous spelling ;-)

Comment: Looks like the NIO method is now deprecated in favor of the IO [method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.html#withCloseable(U,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

Comment: That won't alter its usage though, as it isn't generally called directly

Comment: Would you add an example of how this method is used with a custom Closeable object?

Comment: @jaco0646 - example: `new Socket().withCloseable { socket -> ... }`

Comment: What if you have an AutoCloseable? Out of luck?

Comment: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-nio/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/NioGroovyMethods.java#L1754 says this is `@Deprecated`. Suggests to use https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/01309f9d4be34ddf93c4a9943b5a97843bff6181/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L1620 instead.

Comment: @0x89 that's just if you're calling the method statically...  Which we're not.  When the method is injected into the metaclass of your Closable it will pick the latest one...  The deprecation is there for people building groovy tooling, not standard Groovy users

Comment: "that's just if you're calling the method statically... Which we're not" - what do you mean by "that" - the first link or the second? If you mean the first link does not apply, I don't understand why you were linking to it in the first place.

Comment: It seems to me that there's no example on the internet of how this `withClosable` works... is there any documentation or anything on it? Most importantly, how do I use it with a `java.sql.Connection` or `java.sql.Statement` (not my choice - a Java class is returning them to me.)

Comment: @GregorPetrin that was fixed in 2.5.0 (currently in beta): Implement withCloseable on AutoCloseable (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8251)

Comment: Please give example ```withCloseable``` code for opening + writing a File to illustrate the usage, as it stands it's just a time-waster reading through the comments & trying to figure this out.

Comment: You wouldn't use this for opening and writing to a file, you'd use `File.withWriter` or `File.withOututputStream`. apologies for wasting your time 

Comment: @tim_yates I think it can still be useful in some cases, e. g. for `ZipFile`, which can't be used with `withWriter` nor `withOutputStream` (as it merely represents the ZIPs directory) but still must be closed. It provides `AutoCloseable` interface, so it can be used with `withCloseable`. I think this would be a good example.

Comment: Example: new FileWriter( '/tmp/d.txt' ).withClosable {
  it.println 'd'
} . More examples: https://github.com/timyates/groovy-common-extensions?tab=readme-ov-file#withclosable

Answer (score 11):

Simplest try-with-resources for all Groovy versions is the following (even works with `AutoCloseable` interface).  Where class `Thing` is a closeable class or implements `AutoCloseable`.

```
new Thing().with { res ->
    try {
        // do stuff with res here
    } finally {
        res.close()
    }
}
```

Which is the equivalent in later versions of Groovy doing:

```
new Thing().withCloseable { res ->
    // do stuff with res here
}
```