# Groovy multiple resource closure

Tags: groovy, try-with-resources

I'm using the resource closure feature of Groovy, and was wondering if it was possible to create one closure that manages two resources.  For example, if I have the following two separate closures, is it possible to create one closure that manages both?  Or do I really have to nest the closures?

```
new File(baseDir, 'haiku.txt').withWriter('utf-8') { writer ->
    writer.writeLine 'Into the ancient pond'
}
```

---

```
new Scanner(System.in).with { consoleInput ->
    println consoleInput.nextLine()
}
```

Comment: Maybe this link can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382079/groovy-try-with-resources-construction-analogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The syntax `method(arg) {}` is an alternative syntax to `method(arg, {})`, thus, you can do this:

```
fn = { writer ->
    writer.writeLine 'Into the ancient pond'
}

new File(baseDir, 'haiku.txt').withWriter('utf-8', fn) 

new Scanner(System.in).with(fn)
```

Note that the closure must contain expected code for both method invocations.